# Does this sequence have an $n$th term? $-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, logic

So my sequence is actually

$$-\frac16, 0, \frac{1}{120}, 0, -\frac{1}{5040}, 0, \frac{1}{362880}$$

which can be simplified to

$$-1/3! \ , \ \ 0\ , \ \ 1/5!\ , \ \ 0, \ \ -1/7!\ , \ \ 0\ , \ \ 1/9!$$

I've figured out the denominator would be $(n+3)!$ (My sequence starts with $n=0$).

I've tried a lot of ways with $(-1)^n$ etc. to get the negatives and positives right but can't figure that out, nor how to get the zeroes in the nth term.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider something related to $\cos\dfrac{n\pi}2$ or $\dfrac{i^n+(-i)^n}2$

Comment: There is another way, not convenient at all, but it generalizes to any periodic pattern: consider the complex $n$th roots of $1$, $\omega^k$ with $\omega=\exp(2i\pi/n)$. Then if the period is $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$, consider the Lagrange interpolation polynomial defined by $P(\omega^k)=a_k$ for $0\le k\lt n$. Hence for all $k\in\Bbb N$, $a_k=P(\omega^k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use trig functions $\sin(x)$ and/or $\cos(x)$. Adjust their period using $ k\pi x$ where $k$ is some real number.
(if you don't want to mess with complex numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid trig functions and imaginary numbers, try

$$(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}\left(1+(-1)^n\over2\right)$$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer (aka "floor") function. This gives the sequence $-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,\ldots$ starting with $n=0$.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid the greatest integer function as well, this'll do:

$$-(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}\left(1+(-1)^n\over2\right)$$

The expression $n(n+1)/2$ gives $0,1,3,6,10,15,21,\ldots$, which, for even $n$ alternates between even and odd.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2} + (-1)^{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2}}2$$

The idea is that $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ has the pattern $$\text{odd}, \text{odd}, \text{even}, \text{even}$$
and $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2$ has the pattern$$\text{odd}, \text{even}, \text{even}, \text{odd}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This sequence may be given by $$i^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}.$$ Hope this helps!

Comment: This is incorrect. Plugging in $n=3$ gives $-1$, while the sequence in the title has third term $1$.

Comment: @KReiser Oops, I didn't open my eyes well. I thought all the ones were negative!

Comment: @KReiser This has been corrected. Thank you for drawing my attention to it.